# Would removing the sub-title and its contents make my question more acceptable for this stack?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I have a question about my Politics Stack Exchange post: [The founders of America had a belief that men should be armed as an hedge against tyranny](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/42557/the-founders-of-america-had-a-belief-that-men-should-be-armed-as-an-hedge-agains)

If you see the subtitle *Researched Opinion*. If I remove this title and its contents would that allow a more answerable question?

Comment: I've seen the help center with the term subjective. Being that if I can't back it up then it should be off topic. But, how do I back up a claim without indulging too deep? I can take quotes of the founding fathers to support the claim that they believed in private ownership of arms. I'm having some difficulty in making this on topic. And, I'll admit its tempting to word it in a debate style...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your question is that it doesn't really read like a question. It reads like a political argument you want to make and then in the last paragraph you ask for proof to confirm that argument. You explicitly ask for "definitive proof that [your argument is correct]", you are not even interested in any proof to the contrary.

This looks as if you didn't come to this website with an open mind and that you might not be willing to accept any answers which challenge your conclusions.

Please keep in mind that we try to phrase questions on this website from a neutral point of view. You might already have a very strong opinion about the topic of the question. If you are looking for an audience to read your opinions to, then Stack Exchange is not really the right platform for that.

As the article "[What topics can I ask about here?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)" section on the help center reads:

> Politics Stack Exchange is for objective questions about governments, policies and political processes.
>
> It is not a place to advance opinions or debate, but rather for exchanging objective information about the policies, processes, and personalities that comprise the political arena.

So how do we fix this question?

1. Phrase the title as a question: "Did the founders of America had a belief that men should be armed as an hedge against tyranny?"
2. Remove the whole paragraph "Researched Opinion". It doesn't belong into a question. If anything, it might be an answer. But as an answer it would likely get downvoted, because [we generally don't like one-sided answers based on personal opinion either](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2655/help-i-am-being-oppressed-why-do-people-keep-downvoting-my-opinions).
3. Don't ask for proof that your interpretation of the 2nd amendment is correct. Ask for any statements from the founding fathers which might hint whether it is correct or not. You might leave the statements you already found to show that you already did some research. But you should admit that they are not particularly clear statements about this point.
4. Remove the link to what you wrote on Quora, because it isn't relevant to the question. This really just looks like self-promotion.

(and by the way: the "founding fathers" of the United States were not a monolithic hive-mind. They disagreed on a lot of things. So a statement from one of them should not be seen as canonical truth about what "the founding fathers" believed. Not without knowing if other founding fathers agreed with that statement or spoke out against it)

Comment: Based on researched opinion? Based on material that I've read? One should not be downvoted for making an informed opinion on recorded quotations of the founders. Maybe as an answer, it can be re-worded better. But, thank you for your answer. I should be objective.

Comment: I have removed that subtitle and its contents. Hopefully, it could be an informed opinion that could be worded better.

Comment: @TravisWells As I tried to explain to you: We really don't like opinions on this website. No matter if you call them "informed" or "researched". We expect people to post neutral information and then let the reader form their own opinion. If you want people to read about your opinions, then you might want to write a blog.

Comment: Well, I did remove the Quora link. Hopefully, can it be re-opened?

Comment: Your question is still, fundamentally, a statement of your opinion, quotes that you say support your opinion, and a request for further confirmation of your opinion.  As has already been stated, this is not the kind of objective question that fits here, and thus I cannot vote to reopen in its current form.

Comment: @JoeC Then why not remove those quotes? You know what I think I will.. It will, however, make the question details very empty. :(

Comment: @TravisWells (disclaimer: I am a semi-casual participant on this site) I think it would be fine for you to ask the question "what did the founding fathers think" and then post your own answer with the results of your research.  Do be prepared for criticism of the answer if it is one-sided, though. :-)  With regard for the heterogeneity of the "founding fathers'" opinions, I wholeheartedly agree.  That's why they had all those debates in developing the constitution.  If you could uncover and collect material showing the diversity or range of opinions on the topic, that could be very valuable.

Comment: @phoog You know what I think we should cover both sides of the founding fathers' debates in order to make a neutral answer/question. This is the best way. I'm becoming interested in the politics of this time period.