# You mods reverse my question

Tags: discussion

I am referring to [**this question.**](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/43613/first-3-questions-to-be-answered-love-blood-are-japanese-serial-killers-wha)

I have no more data to quote. Otherwise I consider you all the European hypocrits.

Comment: Statistically on stack exchange, wouldn't that be Americah hypocrites rather than European

Comment: I don't know which. My "second question" is on the line. Only the problem is the length of the translation. I can not copy such things in the original question as they are.

Comment: I personally can not tolerate that my country is the front victim of whale catching **despite the fact the catch limit was set under 1.0**! This is insane enough!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Help! I am being oppressed! Why do people keep downvoting my opinions?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2655/help-i-am-being-oppressed-why-do-people-keep-downvoting-my-opinions)

Comment: I do not understand this question. Is it a complaint about an observed fact, a call/order to 'mod-action', an inquiry into 'what happened and why'? Given that the question on main is now deleted, a bit more data might need quoting here, as most will probably not be able to follow the link. Currently, this meta question is utterly unclear to me and it needs an edit to make some sense.

Answer (score 8):

Your question was downvoted, closed and deleted not because people disagree with the points you make. It was received badly because you are not using this website in the way it should be used.

To quote the help center article [What topics can I ask about here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Politics Stack Exchange is for objective questions about governments, policies and political processes.
>
> It is not a place to advance opinions or debate, but rather for exchanging objective information about the policies, processes, and personalities that comprise the political arena.

The post very obviously doesn't want to ask a question, it wants to advance an opinion and start a debate. That makes it off-topic on this website.

If you come to this website with the intention to convince other people that Japan should be allowed to hunt whales, you are not using this website the way it is intended to be used. We simply don't want political activism on this website, no matter if we agree or disagree with it. If you want people to become aware of a political issue and read your opinions about it, then there are plenty of websites around which are intended for political activism like that. Twitter, Facebook, Reddit, YouTube and many others. But Politics Stack Exchange isn't one of them.

Answer (score 4):

The mods doesn't do anything to the question: the community members voted to close it.  This probably isn't because of your political position on whaling.  It is because it is an incoherent ramble with no obvious question being asked.

There may be a question worth asking buried in there somewhere, but if there is how would it be different to your pervious question on whaling?

Comment: Mods can reverse it. That's what modes did in the past. If you don't like my question, then tell me honestly.