# There's an extremely strong anti China and anti Russian bias

Tags: discussion, questions, bias

[What benefits does China gain by waiving debt to African countries like this?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/74898/what-benefits-does-china-gain-by-waiving-debt-to-african-countries-like-this)

There's an extremely strong anti China and anti Russian bias. Not only I am getting downvotes, but people are also saying things that are completely false about news and reports from U.S. sources when they go against the narratives they choose to believe in (China is bad, is worse than the West) even if those things are not even related to the question, and they try to make China look bad every chance they get even if it's not even related to the question at all.

Comment: People downvoting doesn't mean they are anti China or Russia

Comment: Were some comments deleted, and do you have other questions as examples? Because that question currently has 2 downvotes and comments by only one user, and even if those 2-3 users are biased that doesn't seem like "extremely strong" bias.

Comment: The question is currently at +1, but even if it was negatively-scored, that wouldn't be an indicator of anti-China bias. It might just mean that the question can be improved in some way.

Comment: Related question: [Help! I am being oppressed! Why do people keep downvoting my opinions?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2655/help-i-am-being-oppressed-why-do-people-keep-downvoting-my-opinions)

Comment: I often get downvotes with zero explanation whatsoever. Anyway your Q has two DVs and 4 UVs, so that hardly looks like much of a site-wide bias as you claim.

Comment: Aside, as I was typing a comment under the (only) answer, I noticed 2 DVs rolling in on the anwer (they were like literally seconds apart). That's why wrote there I wasn't DV-ing. There's still zero explanation for DVs on the answer.

Comment: At the moment, the linked question is +4/-2.  I am not sure that's a good example.  If you have other examples, it may help to add them to this meta question to give people a better idea of whether this is a pattern.

Answer (score 1):

So you said

> China doesn't own much of Africa's debt anyway

and you point to articles arguing that it's not a debt *trap* because in the authors' opinion China finances stuff not that different from what the World Bank did or does (like infrastructure).

In your mind the two issues ("doesn't own much of Africa's debt anyway" and debt *trap*) seem to be synonymous, but in others' they are [not, e.g. WaPo writes](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/2021/02/26/pandemic-has-worsened-africas-debt-crisis-china-other-countries-are-stepping/#:%7E:text=As%20Africa%27s%20largest%20bilateral%20creditor,accounts%20for%20almost%20a%20third.):

> As Africa's largest bilateral creditor, China holds at least 21 percent of African debt — and payments to China account for nearly 30 percent of 2021's debt service, as shown in the figure below. Angola alone accounts for almost a third.

Of course, one can quibble what percentage is "much".