# Is political science on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I am reading a paper that claims (without citation) that triangularity in international relations has been criticised by political scientists as vague. I have searched the papers that have cited seminal papers on triangularity without finding examples of such criticism.

Are questions on political science on topic? Would a question about critiques of triangularity in international relations be better suited for a different SE site?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming "triangularity" in your question is [what I think it is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_diplomacy), the subject is on-topic.

While our [help page](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) doesn't explicitly make international or diplomatic relations a subject, it falls under "policies introduced by governments", broadly construed, and I don't recall such questions being closed, or the matter even being considered remotely controversial as to be discussed on meta.

As for political science and/or theory being a valid topic, that [did come up](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2898/should-we-change-the-help-center-to-mention-that-political-theory-is-on-topic) on meta ([more than once](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2646/would-focusing-more-on-political-science-improve-the-site/)) with suggestions to improve the help page, which I'm not sure they were acted upon though. But nobody suggested in those discussions that matter is off-topic.