# Question and answer that do not link any sources

Tags: discussion

What can I do about an answer that is accepted, but user refuses to provide any sources to his claims. A different but similar question is marked as a duplicate. Some other answers to similar questions link to that original answer as a reference.

[How does the judicial independence in Poland after the reforms compare to other EU countries?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/21999/how-does-the-judicial-independence-in-poland-after-the-reforms-compare-to-other)

Comment: Are you asking about the question or answer? I assume the answer since you commented on that?

Comment: about the answer

Comment: Also, your tone in that's answer's comments is far from ideal, to say the least. I also wouldn't be particularly inclined to engage like that.

Comment: I asked for sources, how difficult is to provide sources if there are any? That's ridiculous, they wrote the answer like something obvious, there should have been plenty of sources and yet they can't give any. They don't give the sources as personal favor to me, they should give it for the readers that may be interested in the real answer, not a made up one.

Comment: Yes, that is the tone I mean, and that is also why I am tapping out of this discussion and downvoting this :-)

Comment: it is my right to be outraged by a lie

Comment: It certainly is. However, neither comments nor Meta is where you should be expressing your outrage. Stop doing that, please.

Answer (score 4):

Although it would be preferable if all our answers were backed up with references, it is *not* required. There is nothing wrong with *politely* asking for sources, however, people are free to refuse or even ignore your request.

You are more than welcome to downvote an answer you don't feel is sufficiently backed. Also, there's nothing stopping you from posting your own answer.

---

Related:

- [Should we have a "back it up" rule for answers?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/40/101)