# Can we have a "references" tag in politics.meta.SE?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

A number of question on meta and occasional discussions deal with whether certain assertions need to be supported by references.  [There was also a question](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40/should-we-have-a-back-it-up-rule-for-answers/) about whether *all* questions should be required to have references.  Now that there is an active flag that is (on occasion) applied to questions which some believe require additional references, it is probably reasonable to expect more meta questions about references vs arguments which stand on their own merits.  Can we have a new meta tag for these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, and it's already here: [references](/questions/tagged/references).