# Is a source necessary for a publicly-verifiable fact?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, questions

There's a question concerning an alleged waning of Trump support with a [top-rated answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/53002/5559) - this top-rated answer goes into detail about the reasoning around why support for Trump is waning, but does not provide any citations for their answer.

The facts of their answer seem to be reasonable, but the lack of sources concerns several commenters including myself.  The answerer has asserted in comments that sources are not necessary for what are easily found publicly held stances of Donald Trump.

For this to be a proper answer, should the answerer be adding sources to their statements?  Is it required that the stance of a public political individual be cited to provide an answer based on their public political stance?

Comment: Related: [Should we have a “back it up” rule for answers?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/40/101)

Comment: @yannis Might be a duplicate actually - should I leave this question up or remove it as a duplicate?

Comment: I would leave it as-is and accept the duplicate. I started a vote so you should have a handy box now