# Is there freedom of speech here?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

Is there freedom of speech here?Just two or three biased votes are enough to deprive a person of his right to express himself. Is this sector a breeding ground for regional discrimination, or will the empire have its final carnival?In fact, [my question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/82958/since-the-end-of-cold-war-why-is-it-that-in-every-international-conflict-and-reg) was not malicious. I was just curious about this new public opinion environment and asked some curious questions about your so-called freedom of speech.

Comment: This isn't what you're asking about, but since your profile contains a couple of misconceptions, I thought I'd clear them up for you. Downvotes and delete votes are two different things - three downvotes does not automatically delete an answer as you imply - and your account has demonstrably *not* been suspended.

Comment: @F1Krazy My first answer was fortunately deleted by the moderator. I feel honored that it allowed me to experience the taste of "freedom of speech" for the first time from the "closed and oppressive" public opinion environment. Thank you and thank you for this platform! Finally, I would like to thank every voter who is unwilling to face opposition!

Comment: @yamakaze You mean [this answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/82849/3135)?

Comment: @Philipp Yes, and there are two more

Comment: Well, that's how we do things on this website. This is a question&answer website, not a discussion forum. We expect answers to answer the question that was asked, nothing more and nothing less. Personal opinions and political commentary are against the idea of this website. If you don't like that, then there are plenty of other online platforms available where you can exercise your "freedom of speech" and let the world know your opinions. But Stack Exchange is not one of them.

Comment: I have no objection to the fact that stackoverflow is essentially a question and answer website. But I really can’t agree with the political aspect, because there is no definite answer in politics. Those that have already happened can be deduced from the results to be right or wrong, but those that are happening now or will happen in the future, the results are undecided, so the only way left is to discuss. Still, I'll respect the way this site works and I won't post this trivial stuff as an answer anymore. Finally, thank you for your contribution to the political sector.

Comment: You could create your own website and post there anything you want... that is if you are lucky and live in a country with freedom of speech. Here we want to select for useful questions centered on a common topic. That kind of limits the choice a bit. Sorry if you have had a bad experience but for us it's a lot of work too, constantly cleaning up so the resource remains useful. I could go into details why your question was closed or downvoted, but other answers here have done that already. Don't take it too personal. You could learn from others and would certainly improve very quickly.

Comment: @yamakaze A lot of questions in politics can and do have definite answers. The rules of the site do a good job of telling you the types of questions that don't have definite answers are actually frowned upon or rejected entirely. While less talked about, this site very much appreciates clear evidence of effort, conversely, it punishes what is perceived as lazy. A single sentence answer containing typos will typically not be well received. If you have a genuine question, but don't know how to ask it properly, ask anyway with a specific note or added comment asking for help to clarify it.

Answer (score 9):

Two points:

1. "Freedom of speech" in the legal sense only applies to government suppression of speech or communicative acts. The US, European, and most industrialized nation governments do not interfere with Politics Stack Exchange (PSE) postings one way or another — as opposed to the governments of China, Russia, and certain more dictatorial regimes — so that legal boundary is rarely if ever crossed.
2. "Freedom of speech" in the colloquial sense has various meanings. If you mean it to suggest completely open discourse then no, PSE is not completely free. This is a moderated site, where questions and answers are vetted for quality, suitability, and various unpleasant tricks and tactics, all to keep the quality of the site above a certain benchmark. On the other hand, if you mean "Freedom of speech" to mean the ability to ask and answer any question so long as the text is respectfully written and responsibly constructed, then yes, PSE fosters free speech

Your linked question has some obvious weaknesses. First, it's factually inaccurate. The 'shadow of the US' did not hang over Russia's conflict with the Chechens or Ukraine; it had little to do with the Iran/Iraq war; it wasn't involved with the attacks on the Rohingya or the Uighurs; the Arab Spring caught it by surprise… The US has an oversized military posture since the end of the cold war, and that leads it (sometimes) to get involved with world conflicts, but by far it isn't generally the source of those conflicts.

Second, the framing of the question — perhaps innocently or accidentally — gives the impression that it isn't a question at all, but in fact an assertion: a polemic point that the community is challenged to confirm or deny. Those types of rhetorical questions in which a question format is used to promote a confrontational position are frowned on here. The site prefers honest questions seeking meaningful answers, not opinions tossed out to stir things up.

There might be an honest question lying somewhere within the apparent polemic; a hefty rewrite might bring that out and create a good question.

Answer (score 4):

Your Q is rather vague

> Since the end of Cold war, why is it that in every international conflict and regional turmoil, the **shadow** of the United States can always be found? What does this phenomenon mean? Can the world achieve lasting peace by solving this root cause?

What does that "shadow" mean exactly?

And your subsequent comments like

> My point is that no major power is as eager for conflict as the United States **right now**.

appear to be from an alternate reality or some propaganda bubble.

From help

> Politics Stack Exchange is for **objective** questions about governments, policies and political processes.
>
> It is **not a place to advance opinions or debate**, but rather for exchanging objective information about the policies, processes, and personalities that comprise the political arena. If you can't [back it up](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40/should-we-have-a-back-it-up-rule-for-answers), it's subjective.

And yeah, Qs that asked if the world would be a better place if some other particular country were to disappear would be likewise closed.

---

Also, rather than post dozens of comments here, on meta on what you meant by that, you should edit the question, which I suspect you still can do, [because](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/281403/3588161) it was not self-deleted. After that, you can flag it for a mod to review and possibly undelete.