# Is it hypocritical to force a subject as opinion-driven as "Politics" into a Stack Exchange format?

Tags: discussion, opinionated

Is it hypocritical or self-contradicting to force a subject as opinion-driven as "Politics" into a Stack Exchange format?

The Stack Exchange Network is notoriously stringent about requiring that answers be fact-based, not opinion-based.

However, I'm not sure opinions can be separated from *politics*, by its very nature. Is the attempt to do so a contradiction?

> **“politics”**
> *definition:* the activities associated with the governance of a country or other area, especially the **debate or conflict** among
> individuals or parties having or hoping to achieve power

If we cannot include matters of **debate or conflict**, which arise due to **differing opinions**, is it constructive to discuss politics in this format at all?

And if all opinion-based discussion is barred (or at least strongly frowned upon), what does that leave us with? Factual reporting on events that have already happened, and polled statistics?

Please help me understand the logic here, if any exists.

Comment: Have you read the "[What topics can I ask about here?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)" help center article yet?

Comment: People having opinions about something does not make that thing totally opinion-based and subjective. People also have opinions about whether the earth is round or whether climate change is occurring, yet these are entirely objectively established facts.

Comment: FYI: what is construed as "opinion based" on P.SE has been discussed numerous times before. https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4163/how-does-primarily-opinion-based-work-on-this-site is a good place to start.

Answer (score 3):

No, there are plenty of aspects about politics that are not opinion driven that can be addressed on this site. In fact people have been able to ask over 10,000 questions on the site without having issues of the questions being opinion based.

Answer (score 1):

It's not hypocritical.  It's challenging.  What you call "opinions" is really people emphasizing the importance of their priorities over priorities of others.

Recognizing the difference between priorities and the information being discussed involves understanding how changes in priorities change what context is important to the discussion and what context is marginal.

Because people's priorities are always personal to them, it's challenging.  But it's not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it hypocritical or self-contradicting to force a subject as opinion-driven as "Politics" into a Stack Exchange format?

No. There's no such hypocracy.

This site is *about* politics, it is not an *embodiment* of politics.

That said, there is certainly pressure to make it political from a small minority of the community, but good guardrails are in place to keep that from happening.

They're called moderators and community, and they work together to prevent this (or any) SE site from becoming an embodiment of politics.